# The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -600.) Cant run app in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Using XCode 6.3.1 , SDK 8.3

Suddenly my app stopped running in (any) simulator and Xcode throws error

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -600.)

Tried cleaning, reset content and setting and even restarting my Mac.

Is there anything I can do to run my app in simulator.

Comment: You can check this website for more information about OSStatus codes http://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-600

Answer (score 26):

Just quit your iOS Simulator then reopen the simulator then build your source Now it will work.

Answer (score 3):

- if you run on the simulator -> relaunch the simulator
- if you run on real device -> reconnect the device

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue on a 9.1 simulator. I was able to successfully run my app after doing a CLEAN, switching to an 8.4 simulator, compiling (successfully) and then switching back to 9.1 and running.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it just by restarting the computer. Don't know what it means, but it can be fixed that way! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The error code says `procNotFound`. What helped me was simply to reset simulator content and settings, then close it and try to run the project again.

Answer (score 0):

Some LSApplicationQueriesScheme do not work on Simulator. So run it on iPhone device. This worked for me.