# The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10827.)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I reinstall the xcode 7.3.1. But when want to run existing project this error received. How i can resolve it.

Comment: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10827.)

Comment: Pop up show with this message.

Comment: Try these solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836984/the-operation-couldn-t-be-completed-osstatus-error-600-cant-run-app-in-simu

Comment: i try this but same error

Comment: Are you only receiving this error for this particular project? If it's only this project, try changing the bundle ID and running again.

Comment: Basically i already work on project but due to crash of OS. i reinstall it and reinstall xcode tool. But now now i open existing project and want to run. But build success this message received.

Comment: i create new project and run but same error received. And simulator do not open

Comment: And this message received from simlator side. Error returned in reply: Connection invalid

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to delete derived data.
Go to Window->Project->Select Your Project->Press Delete button (to delete derived data).

Now run simulator and hopefully that error should disappear.

Comment: Build succeeded but same error . The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10827.)

Comment: Gotcha. Did you try to reset the contents and settings of the simulator? Try to 1. Clean build (SHIFT-CMD-K) 2. Reset contents and settings of simulator 3. Delete Derived Data 4. Build and run

Comment: i create new project and run but same error received. And simulator do not open

Comment: And this message received from simlator side. Error returned in reply: Connection invalid

Comment: I follow your 4 step and then close xcode and open xcode Now it is working fine.