# iOS Xcode 10 Simulator Error (OSStatus error -600)

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

Since upgrading to Mojave I have been getting the following error when I try to run the simulator.

[image]

The simulator runs when you acknowledge the error, but the app is not uploaded from Xcode to the simulator.

If I connect an actual device I can build and run the app no problem. I have tried this with a few different apps so it doesn't appear to be app specific.

The log in the Mac console shows:

```
default 11:13:49.003902 +1000   Xcode    iOSSimulator: Could not launch simulator: -600
default 11:13:49.004097 +1000   Xcode    iOSSimulator: <DVTiPhoneSimulator (0x7fd0b309d380), iPhone X, unknown class, 12.2 (16E226), FAA893B1-BCCB-402E-87DD-24DC7710B4A5> could not launch simulator for com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator
```

What I have tried:

1. Turn it off and on again. Xcode, simulator and laptop.
2. Cleaned the build folder and deleted derived data.
3. None of the solutions from [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836984/the-operation-couldn-t-be-completed-osstatus-error-600-cant-run-app-in-simu) worked.
4. I also tried the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52500234/ios-simulator-crash-on-xcode-10) (albeit it was a different error) but it doesn't work either.
5. I looked up OSStatus error -600 on google - it is [procNotFound](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-600), which didn't really help much. It means no eligible process with specified descriptor

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Note that the latest version of Xcode (v10.3) seems to have fixed this issue. You will need to reboot your computer after upgrading to see or add simulators. I would try this approach first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restart the computer (not just Xcode). Then go into Library / Developer / CoreSimulator / Devices and throw everything in the trash. Then launch Xcode, go into Devices and Simulators, and delete all simulators from the Simulators pane. Now create one simulator in the Simulators pane. You will be able to build and run on it.

**EDIT** The OP reports that even this was insufficient to clean out the problematic dead simulators. It was also necessary to say `xcrun simctl delete unavailable` in the Terminal.

Comment: Thanks matt - I deleted all the old simulators listed and added a new one. But then I am back with error -600.

Comment: What did end up working was then shutting down Xcode and the simulator and then running the command "xcrun simctl delete unavailable" in Terminal. I think your actions contributed to the cure, so you get the points!

Comment: Ok but I really should add your solution to my answer because comments are ephemeral. That way we have a better chance of helping others!